# Rancher 2.6 Bind-Mount Docker & Minecraft

Tags: docker, storage, minecraft, rancher

Been following the tutorial of 'TechnoTim' (specifically the video entitled "Docker, Rancher, Kubernetes... Minecraft? (Rancher Setup and Install Tutorial)") to set up minecraft using docker and Rancher.

Unfortunately, when a pod dies or is killed, the server goes with it (not persisted).

I have tried using the recommended bound-mount settings as described in the video (which I believe is the normal way of resolving this)

[bind-mount (techno-tim)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHYZx.png)

I have also tried to modify the YAML as per itzg:

```
volumes:
  # attach a directory relative to the directory containing this compose file
  - ./minecraft-data:/data
```

When looking at the pod, I can see the files are being generated (hence being able to connect to the server) but when I look at the filesystem there is nothing present

I'm sure I'm missing something or doing something stupid so any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused by following the tutorial without thinking...

"Mount Point" needs to refer to the location that the pod uses (that may or may not exist on disk).

"Path On Node" refers to the mapped location on disk.

In the tutorial 'mc' is used as the "Mount Point" but this is not what is actually used by the pod (could be that things have updated since).

Running Shell Command against the pod shows the initial location (in my case it was /data). This is what needs to be used for the "Mount Point" if using the Rancher UI